# Find last version (major, minor) of some information

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with versioned information for several companies.

```
|Useful info | major | minor | week_id | company_id |
---------------------------------------|------------|
|************|   1   |   0   | 2015_01 |     1      |
|************|   1   |   1   | 2015_01 |     1      |
|************|   2   |   0   | 2015_01 |     1      |
|************|   1   |   0   | 2015_01 |     2      |
|************|   1   |   1   | 2015_01 |     2      |
```

So, for each week, I need to get the information corresponding to the last version (max (major, minor))

I tried :

```
select * from my_table
where (major, minor) = max(major, minor)
group by compatny_id, week_id
```

It did not work because `max()` is not supposed to take several arguments.

So I decided to change `(major, minor)` to `100 * major + minor`. I tried :

```
select * from my_table
where (company_id, week_id, 100 * major + minor) in 
(
  select sec_semaine_cinema_id, cpx_complexe_id, max(100 * dlo_version_major + dlo_version_minor)
  from demande_log_dlo
  group by sec_semaine_cinema_id, cpx_complexe_id
)
```

This works! **But**: It will obviously force a full scan.

Do you have a better solution?

(I am using Postgresql 9.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (company_id, week_id) t.*
from my_table t
order by company_id, week_id, major desc, minor desc;
```

If you prefer to use more standard SQL, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by company_id, week_id order by major desc, minor desc) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```